# How to prove the continuity of the function of several at $(0,0)$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, continuity

How to verify the continuity of the following function at $(0,0)$ :

\begin{cases}f(x,y)=\cfrac{x^3}{x^2+y^2}& \text{if } (x,y)\neq (0,0)\\
f(0,0)=0\end{cases}

Answer (score 1):

In polar coordinates :
$$\frac{x^3}{x^2+y^2}=\frac{r^3\cos^3\theta}{r^2}=r\cos^3\theta$$
And when $r\rightarrow 0,\forall \theta, f(r,\theta)\rightarrow0$.

So $f$ is indeed continuous.

Answer (score 1):

Now ..I find another solution...$$|x^2|<|x^2+y^2|$$
$$\implies \frac{1}{|x^2+y^2|}\leq\frac{1}{|x^2|}$$
$$\implies\frac{|x^3|}{|x^2+y^2|}\leq |x|$$
And hence the given function is continuous at (0,0).